# How to discover what story the song is trying to convey?

Tags: classical-music

Someone said to me that the song Tempest from Beethoven is about someone in a hurry to get into a ship to travel. However, I didn't find anything on the internet about this story or any story. At that time, they also said the stories about other songs. How can I find these stories?

Comment: By "the song Tempest from Beethoven", do you mean the first movement (or maybe all 3 movements combined) of Ludwig van Beethoven's "Tempest" piano sonata?

Comment: At that day, they played "Beethoven Sonata No 17 'Tempest' Mov 3 Allegretto" before saying that, but I don't know if what they said relates just to this movement or the song altogether.

Comment: Sounds to me like the cart is in front of the horse.

Comment: Should the question be what song the story is trying to convey?

Comment: Is this an answerable question for this stack? It seems to me the answer is "google" (or your preferred search engine).

Comment: Well, I wouldn't come here without searching for it on some search engine. Also, as you should know, search engines don't have answers, but websites indexed do. Therefore, the answer has to be on some website like this.

Comment: @Matheus: Fair enough, but I just wonder what you would expect from an answer on a question as generic as "how do I find out what is the story behind a song". If the story is known, it's most likely google-able, if it's not you will get a personal opinion.

Comment: I was expecting some kind of website or books that I could find such information. For example, I would recommend janedoe-teas.com (hypothetical website not very known with everything about tea) if someone asked me about where to find something related with tea.

Comment: But, reading Laurence's answer, I guess I didn't find some story behind some songs because actually there aren't a story behind them. I just tried to look for the story behind Tempest and it was easy to find (and maybe this is what you are saying).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes (but not very often) a piece of music is consciously programmatic, literally describing a story.   Richard Strauss does this in his 'Don Quixote' and 'Till Eulenspiege'.   This is taken to extremes in the type of movie scoring known as 'Mickey Mousing' where every action on screen is matched by the music.  (Even with the most extreme 'Mickey Mousing' it can be interesting to try to reconstruct the action from hearing JUST the music. Description is not definition.)

Sometimes (and rather more often) a piece describes a situation, mood or emotion.  There are many pieces that are labelled 'Storm'.  Or 'Pastorale' describing peaceful countryside.   The description may be supplied by the composer, quite often it's tagged on afterwards by someone else!

There isn't often an actual story to be told.

Comment: Speaking of Mickey Mousing, Spastic Ink's "A Wild Hare" is a pretty impressive example (IMO) of Mickey Mousing progressive metal music to scenes from the movie *Bambi* (as made apparent in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q_p7lLId9Xk and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UhP4lg28fs0).